# Convert date string with mothns in German into DateTime object

Tags: php, date, converters

I have a time string which is formated (nearly) with this format `M j Y H:iA`. 
The Problem is, that the month is localized in german. So instead of "Dec 31 2014 12:00AM" there is "Dez 31 2014 12:00AM".

This is what I tried already but did not work. `$date` is `false`;

```
$input = 'Dez 31 2014 12:00AM';
$format = 'M j Y H:iA';

$oldLocale = setlocale(LC_TIME, 0);
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'de_DE.utf8', 'deu_deu');
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $input);
setlocale(LC_TIME, $oldLocale);

$out = $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Is there a way to parse that string without manual string parsing?

Comment: Did you tried to do the same, but use `DateTime`'s creator instead of `createFromFormat` method? Or test it on `date_create` function (procedural version of `DateTime`'s creator). It should "eat" nearly everything, including German month names, if locale is set to German.

Comment: what you mean by parse without manual string parsing? do some config setting and parse the string automatically .. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Comment: @trejder I did try `date_create_from_format`. It does not "eat" it as well.
@zod I mean parsing with e.g. `preg_match and replacing` Dez with Dec. I did that and it is a solution so far but not really automatic. And for strftime I need a timestamp first or do I mis something?

Comment: No, I mean [`date-create`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php) (an alias [`DateTime`'s constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)), not `date_create_from_format`. I don't even know the latter one. But I did use `date_create` successfully for parsing locale dates (for example in Polish).